# How to integrate twitter, facebook social sharing api in Phonegap 2.7.0

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, cordova

I am trying to integrate twitter social sharing api to share links from my phone gap application.

as i have read from the blog given here

http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms

Its is asking to install ChildBrowser plugin first.

I have downloaded the plugin from github as

https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser

And as i have tried to install it in my project the java file is giving too much errors.

As i have tried to resolve errors with suggestion given in eclipse. And when i run the project as android application it is saying exec() unknown plugin ChildBrowser

I am adding the plugin in config.xml as

```
<plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="android.com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>
```

I Just want to clear that the child browser plugin works with PhoneGap 2.7.0 Or not . If not then  how can i use twitter sharing for my app.

If i am wrong anywhere please correct me. And also is there any best way to implement social sharing in phonegap application

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for PhoneGap social sharing, there is a much easier way. Just [use the plugin mentioned here](http://www.x-services.nl/phonegap-share-plugin-facebook-twitter-social-media/754) and you'll be able to share images via the native sharing widget, or directly to Twitter or Facebook.

[image: The native sharing widget on iOS 7]

Comment: Hi Eddy, thanks for reply man, i have already resolved my issue and used the social share plugin and also i have used the last version of this plugin because i was using phonegap 2.7.0, any way thanks man for your reply.... And one issue i am not able to share predefind message on facebook in the plugin given here https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/tree/phonegap-2.x/ any idea .... thanks

Comment: Hi, that's a limitation of Facebook unfortunately. Facebook wants the user to enter the text, so the post is more personal. Can't do anything about that :(

Comment: Thanks #Eddy thanks allot, so it means even with updated plugin working with phonegap 3+ we can't send a predefind message. and Eddy if you don't mind can i have your email id. Thanks

Comment: Correct, Facebook just doesn't allow it. The only way to post to Facebook directly is using a FacebookConnect plugin, but it's more difficult to setup. My email: eddyverbruggen[at]gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Use simple InAppBrowser

Twitter Sharing url

```
var tweeter_url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text='+your_text_or_share_url;

var ref = window.open(tweeter_url, 'random_string', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
                   console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
} );
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
     console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);

     if(event.url == 'https://mobile.twitter.com/'){

         setTimeout(function() {
                    ref.close();
         }, 1000);
     }

} );
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
                  //console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
} );
```

Facebook Sharing url

```
var facebook_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=your_app_id&link="+encodeURIComponent(urlPost)+"&picture="+encodeURIComponent(urlPicture)+"&name="+encodeURIComponent(Title)+"&caption=&description="+encodeURIComponent(message)+"&redirect_uri="+your_redirect_uri;
var ref = window.open(url, 'random_string', 'location=no');

ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
     console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
     var post_id = event.url.split("post_id=")[1];
     var cancel_url = event.url.split("#")[0];
     if(post_id != undefined){
            setTimeout(function() {
                ref.close();                    
            }, 5000);
     }
     if(cancel_url != undefined && cancel_url == your_redirect_uri){
            setTimeout(function() {
                ref.close();                        
            }, 1000);
     }                         
});
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {

});
```